# Keep GitLab.com shared runner from starting default services mysql, postgres, redis

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

(Admittedly, this is not important.)

I'm using GitLab.com CI's shared runners to run my CI builds. They seem to always start the mysql, postgres, and redis services, even though I have the line

```
services: []
```

in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Is there a way to keep the shared runners from starting these services? Admittedly, they don't hurt, other than taking up resources and creating a few lines of noise in the build log.